# If statement is read whereas it shouldn't be read

Tags: c++

I am trying to write code for a go game, only player against player. I created a grid with 81 buttons and when I click on a button I have a callback function which will put a black or white image in the button. I am coding with CC++ and use the FLTK librairy for the graphics.

My problem is that when I am trying to know when coins of the same colour are connected or not an if statement is executed even if a condition is not true.

Here is my function whith the problem :

```
//populates groups into above arrays for the two colors

void populateCheckingVec() 
{
    groupsBlack.clear(); groupsWhite.clear();

    vector<int> boxesChecked;   // I create the diffrent vectors
    vector<int> ToBeChecked;
    vector <int> aroundInd;
    int current=0;
    int groupIndex=0;

    for (int color = 2; (color == 1 || color == 2); color--)  //ColorLoop
    {
        if (color==1) 
        {
            cout<<endl<< "played colour is white" <<endl;
            cout<<endl;
        }
        else if (color==2)
        {
            cout<<"played colour is black "<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
        }

        boxesChecked.clear();

        groupIndex=0;

        vector<vector <int> > &currentColorGroup = ((color==1)?groupsWhite:groupsBlack);

        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(go)/sizeof(*go)); i++) // loop through the grid
        {     
            if (go[i] == color && vectorContains(boxesChecked,i)==-1) //check only through the current color and not an already-checked box
                                                                      // vectorContains gives me -1 if the value (here i) is not in the vector (here boxesChecked) else !=-1.
            {
                if (go[i]!=boxAdj(true, -1, i) && go[i]!=boxAdj(false, -1, i) )   // To get the index, boxAdj(true,-1,i) give me the color at the left of the i element, 
                                                                                  //boxAdj(false, -1, i) gives me the color at the top of the i element  
                {
                    ToBeChecked.push_back(i);
                    cout<<"ToBeChecked's elements are :";
                    for(int l=0; l<ToBeChecked.size(); l++) cout<<ToBeChecked[l]<<", ";
                    cout<<endl;

                    cout<<"Neighboors'loop started"<<endl;

                    while (ToBeChecked.size()>0) 
                    {   
                        cout<< "Begin loop ToBeChecked.size() ="<<ToBeChecked.size()<<endl;

                        for (int j=0; j<ToBeChecked.size(); j++)
                        {
                            if (vectorContains(boxesChecked, ToBeChecked[j])==-1)
                            {
                                current=ToBeChecked[j];
                                cout<<"current is = "<<current<<endl;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        sameColorAround(aroundInd, current); //To get the same coulor around and put the values into the vector aroundInd.
                        cout<<"aroundInd's elements are :";
                        for (int m=0; m<aroundInd.size(); m++) cout<<aroundInd[m]<<", ";
                        cout<<endl;

                        for (int k=0; k<aroundInd.size(); k++)
                        {
                            cout<<"vectorContains(boxesChecked, aroundInd[k] ="<<vectorContains(boxesChecked, aroundInd[k])<<endl;

                            cout<<"boxesChecked's elements are :";
                            for (int w=0; w<boxesChecked.size(); w++) cout<<boxesChecked[w]<<", ";
                            cout<<endl;

                            if (vectorContains(boxesChecked, aroundInd[k]==-1)) 
                            {
                                ToBeChecked.push_back(aroundInd[k]);
                                cout<<"The neighboor is added"<<endl;
                                cout<<"ToBeChecked's elements are  :";
                                for (int x=0; x<ToBeChecked.size(); x++) cout<<ToBeChecked[x]<<", ";
                                cout<<endl;
                            }
                        }
                        ToBeChecked.erase(std::remove(ToBeChecked.begin(), ToBeChecked.end(), current), ToBeChecked.end());
                        boxesChecked.push_back(current);
                        cout<< " ToBeChecked.size() fin ="<<ToBeChecked.size()<<endl;

                        cout<<"ToBeChecked's elements are  :";
                        for (int z=0; z<ToBeChecked.size(); z++) cout<<ToBeChecked[z]<<", ";
                        cout<<endl;
                    }

                    groupIndex+=1;
                    currentColorGroup.resize(groupIndex);

                    for (int n=0; n<boxesChecked.size(); n++)
                    {
                        if (ifAlreadyGrouped(currentColorGroup, boxesChecked[n])==false)
                        {
                        cout<<"n= "<<n<<endl;
                        cout<<"groupIndex ="<<groupIndex<<endl;
                        cout<<"boxesChecked's elements are : "<<boxesChecked[n]<<endl;

                        (currentColorGroup[groupIndex-1]).push_back(boxesChecked[n]);

                        }
                    }

                    ToBeChecked.clear();
                    boxesChecked.clear();
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

My problem is that I have `vectorContains(boxesChecked, aroundInd[k])==0` (see below) and my if statement is executed! All these `cout` are of course to check what is happening, sorry if it is difficult to understand.

I write what is happening on the console after I have clicked on the button `(i=11` (previous clicked : `i=10(black); i=16(white)`) because I can not post images.

Here is what happened when I clicked to the button `(i=11)` and I get my first black-connection

```
player color is black
ToBeChecked's elements are : 10,
Neighboor's loop started
Begin loop ToBeChecked.size()=1
current is = 10
arounfInd's elements are : 11
vectorContains(boxesChecked, aroundInd[k] =-1
boxesChecked's elements are :
The neighboor is added
ToBeChecked's elements are : 10, 11
ToBeChecked.size() end =1
ToBeChecked's elements are : 11
// I have removed 10 from ToBeChecked and added it to boxesChecked
Begin loop ToBeChecked.size()=1
current is = 11

aroundInd's elements are : 10
vectorContains(boxesChecked, aroundInd[k] ==0)
// the if-statement is here
boxesChecked's elements are : 10
The neighboor is added
// The problem is here!  Why the neighboor is added whereas I have ==0 and not -1 ??
ToBeChecked's elements are : 11, 10**
ToBeChecked.size() end=1
ToBeChecked's elements are : 10
```

(the while loop becomes of course infinite after that)

Here below is my vectorContains function:

```
//returns the index for a value in vector

int vectorContains(vector <int> &vect, int val)   
{
    int r = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vect[i] == val)
        {
            r=i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I guess there won't be much people reading that wall of text. please try to narrow down your problem and describe only the particlular problem you have, instead of pouring out your whole project. You might as well read the Stackoverflow FAQ first to get an idea of what kind of questions are fit for the site.

Comment: Also using debbuger instead of `std::cout` would help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is very simple:

```
cout<<"vectorContains(boxesChecked, aroundInd[k] ="<<vectorContains(boxesChecked, aroundInd[k])<<endl;
```

above you display result of `vectorContains`, while here:

```
if (vectorContains(boxesChecked, aroundInd[k]==-1))
```

you pass `aroundInd[k]==-1` as argument to `vectorContains`, and there is no comparison with -1 in this if statement! :)

I guess you wanted:

```
if (vectorContains(boxesChecked, aroundInd[k])==-1)
```

Btw I'd suggest you to split this big function into a few smaller ones.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to see your code for what it really is. Forget what you think you wrote and see what you really wrote.

Comment: Thank you very much Michał Walenciak, 

of course you are right ! I knew it was just a little thing..

And I agree I should split my function, really complicated to understand like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the STL `find` instead of your `vectorContains`:

```
if ((pos_itr = find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), val)) != vect.end()) { // found...
     // do found stuff with *pos_itr
} else { // not found...
     // ...
}
```